# Clojure, core.logic, mini-kanren, Reasoned Schemer

Tags: clojure, logic, clojure-core.logic

### Code

```
(defn ex20 []
  (run*
    [x]
    (resto '(c o r n) (list x 'r 'n))))

(defn ex20a []
  (run*
    [x]
    (resto '(c o r n) `(~x r n))))
```

### Results

```
(ex20) -> (o)
(ex20a) -> ()
```

### Question:

Why? What's going on? Is there some weird interaction between run* and macros?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntax-quote namespaces symbols:

```
(defn ex20a []
  (run* [x]
    (resto `(c o r n) `(~x r n))))
```

or

```
(defn ex20a []
  (run* [x]
    (resto '(c o r n) (list x 'r 'n))))
```

Comment: stupid follow up question: why would I ever want to use ' instead of ` ?